# Why: "Attempting to load .. while deallocating... :UISearchController:"

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have root storyboard that has a button that pushes ViewControllerB.

ViewControllerB has a sort controller `UISortController`.

ViewControllerB has a "back" method that is controlled by the root nav controller.

I'm getting the following warning:

`Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UISearchController: 0x7ff10258ba60>)`

I used [Apple's sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014683) (membership required) to add the new UISearchController.

Has anyone come across this? How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Storyboard Unwind Segues instead: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html

This insightful post also has a wealth of very useful implementation detail:

[What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)

Comment: Good idea. Thanks. I'll try that now.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this. The back function is actually being controlled by the main VC navigation controller. Should I simple override this with my own button?

Comment: Please note, I have updated my question so it is more accurate.

Comment: In that case I would check that you aren't accidentally triggering two backward navigations together. I believe I've seen this error when accidentally attempting that before.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I think that solved the issue. (I have to replicate this in 30+ controllers.).But I will mark it as solved.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you're recommending disabling the UINavigationControllers back button and replacing it with your own as an unwind segue? I'm having a similar issue and checked that I'm not triggering two backward navigations together.

Comment: If you are using a `UINavigationController` you do not need unwind segues, as the navigation controller handles this for you.

I would recommend putting symbolic breakpoints on the `UINavigationController` pop methods and check whether something else is triggering a backwards navigation. Alternatively, temporarily set the `UINavigationControllers` delegate to monitor it's activity.

Comment: @AndrewEbling -- could you please provide an example of this: "Alternatively, temporarily set the UINavigationControllers delegate to monitor it's activity. –" How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: @DavidDelMonte have an object implement the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol methods and log some messages to the console. Then create an instance of that object and assign it to your `UINavigationController`'s `delegate` property. Your implemented delegate methods should get called each time a transition is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the same console error message, but note the following regarding my Xcode project:

- segues to navigation controllers must remain due to their use with a split view controller (to the detail view controller);
- (and according to @AndrewEbling comments above) the code does not require unwind segues as the navigation controller manages (a proportion of) the tasks automatically;
- also the code does not require unwind segues as blocks are used to set properties in parent view controller.

Thanks to comments by Leehro and Clafou in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32955784/1883707) the console error message was suppressed by using following line of code in `viewDidLoad` (note that there is no need to insert this in `dealloc`):

`[self.searchController loadViewIfNeeded];` (note available from iOS 9).